# vagrant provider specific hostmanager settings

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-plugin

Sounds simple - I'm trying to switch the vagrant hostmanager plugin on for Virtualbox only.

So I attempt an overwrite:

```
config.hostmanager.enabled = false

...

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.hostmanager.enabled = true
    ...
end
config.vm.provider "azure" do |azure|
    # do nothing
    ...
end
```

However, vagrant complains about it:

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix the following errors and try again:

VirtualBox Provider:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: hostmanager
```

Edit: I also tried...

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb,override|
    override.hostmanager.enabled = true
    ...
end
```

This doesn't throw an error but it also doesn't run hostmanager either :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I configured something like

```
config.vm.hostmanager.aliases = %w(my.example.local)
```

but correct is

```
config.hostmanager.aliases = %w(my.example.local)
```

Maybe you had a similar typo?